# Editor for collection with numbering

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, editorfor

I use `@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.MyCollection)` to display my list of objects. 
This can be displayed as follows:

```
John Doe
Jane Doe
Jenny Doe
```

Now I want to add a numbering so the above will be displayed as follow:

```
1. John Doe
2. Jane Doe
3. Jenny Doe
```

How can I do this without replacing my @Html.EditorFor with loop?

Answer (score 0):

From this SO answer, try this:

```
<ol>
@for (int i = 0; i < model.MyCollection.Count; i++ )
{
    <li>@Html.EditorFor(m => model.MyCollection[i])</li>
}
</ol>
```

Comment: well..yes I know I can do like that, but I was wondering if I can do this without introducing loop (as I wrote in my question)

Comment: you can if you write your own HTML Helper that extends Html.Editfor and does the same thing - iterates through the collection to return an OL

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: I would get the MVC source here - http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MVC - and look at how Html.EditFor() was built as a starter.